# WSO2 API Manager get user name in backend

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-identity-server

We have a web application where we use API Manager and Identity server together.User logs into web app and get the token and scopes.And web application places the API call with the scope and token.
Now we need to know which user invoked the API so that response can be formed. How can we know which user invoked this API in the backend?
For instance, suppose there is a Student Listing page and Depending on the class teacher who logged in , we have to show the student list.We have that information in our backend database.To get that information , backend has to know the id of the teacher who made the API call..

How to achieve this in WSO2?Any alternative approaches?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 options for this.

1) Enable [JWT token](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM200/Passing+Enduser+Attributes+to+the+Backend+Using+JWT).

2) Set username as an http header using a custom sequence. Read this [blog post](http://movingaheadblog.blogspot.com/2016/08/wso2-api-manager-how-to-retrieve.html) forlearn how to read the username. You can set it as a http heder like this.

```
<property name="UserName" scope="transport" expression="$ctx:api.ut.userName"/>
```

Comment: I enabled JWT Token in API manager.But my request headers doesnt have anything of JWT.What could be wrong?

Comment: I am using a integrated identity server and api manager togother.So where should i enable it?Both API Manager and Idenitity server?

Comment: It should be enabled in Keymanager node. If you're using IS as KM, it should be in IS node.

Comment: Is there a way to get the roles associated with the user via this?

Comment: Yes, JWT should have them.

Comment: Can you tell me exactly which field?

Comment: my bad. looks like roles are not included by default. Have a look at these.
http://sanjeewamalalgoda.blogspot.com/2014/12/how-to-implement-custom-jwt-generator.html
http://wso2.com/library/articles/2014/12/customize-json-web-token-generation-with-wso2-api-manager-1.8.0/

Comment: @Bee, how do I add Custom Sequences in API Manager 1.7?